# Getting indexoutofbounds exception in android

Tags: java, android

I'm getting an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` while removing postions because positions start from 1 but the array index starts from 0. Could you provide an explanation on how to solve this?

```
if (isChecked && groupName.equals(OLIConstants.FAILED_TO_ACTIVATE))
{
    count = count + 1;
    arrActivation.add(childPosition);
    context.getSummaryFragment().getOli(arrActivation,groupPosition);
    if (!context.getSummaryFragment().activateSystem.isEnabled())
    {
        context.getSummaryFragment().enableButton(true);
    }
}
else if (!isChecked && groupName.equals(OLIConstants.FAILED_TO_ACTIVATE))
{
    count = count - 1;
    arrActivation.remove(childPosition);
}

context.getSummaryFragment().getOli(arrActivation,groupPosition);

if (context.getSummaryFragment().activateSystem.isEnabled() && count <= 0)
{
    context.getSummaryFragment().enableButton(false);
}
}
```

Comment: Why can't you just initialize count as one integer greater than it already is?

Comment: Your sample code neither shows count initialisation nor any loop or array object. Post more code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm gonna make an assumption based on your code:

1. childPosition is the data you wanna store in ArrayList arrActivation.

   `arrActivation.add(childPosition);`
2. childPosition is an integer (because you're getting an array index out of bound exception.

   `arrActivation.remove(childPosition);`

Now, if you try to add an integer and remove it using the same parameter, you might get the AIOOB exception. Take a look:

```
    ArrayList here = new ArrayList();
    here.add(5);
    // The following line will exception because
    // The length of the array list is 1 at this point
    here.remove(5);
```

But this will work:

```
    ArrayList here = new ArrayList();
    here.add(5);
    // The following line will not exception 
    here.remove(Integer.valueOf(5));
```

Because now we're using the remove(Object o) (which finds the data with Object o, and remove the first occurance) function instead of the remove(int index) (which tries to remove the arraylist's index's index) function.

I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You can access array by using `arrActivation.add(childPosition-1);`

Hope this will solve your issue.